# Using EPPlus to read a large excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, epplus

Hi I've got a question about EPPlus and reading a large excel file into a database. The code that I've made is quite quick for small sheets but super, super slow for large sheets (where rows are over 5000).

I'm using code like this

```
for (int i = workSheet.Dimension.Start.Row;
         i <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;
         i++)
{
    for (int j = workSheet.Dimension.Start.Column;
             j <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Column;
             j++)
    {
         object cellValue = workSheet.Cells[i, j].Value;
    }
}
```

So that's going through all rows and columns and getting each cell value.
I'm going to investigate but just checking if anyone else has done it before me.

Would it be quicker to read the row e.g

```
for (int i = workSheet.Dimension.Start.Row;
             i <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;
             i++)
    {

             var row = workSheet.Cells[i, 1,i,workSheet.Dimension.End.Column];

    }
```

Would this be quicker?

Comment: `Would this be quicker?` - Was it quicker when you tried it?

Comment: "_[You can also use the GetValue and SetValue methods directly on the worksheet object. (This will give a little bit better performance than reading/writing via the range)](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Reading-and-Writing-Data)_"

Comment: how many columns you have? 
I have tested your code with 6000 rows and 10 columns and it is lasting less than a second

Comment: I would say that it is the logic inside for loop that is consuming time.

Comment: Thanks for the input, it's interesting the feedback. Yahya have you tried 6000rows 10columns in about 20 tabs. Then going round each worksheet doing the same? I'm dealing with an excel of about 13MB that has some images (which I don't need) so probably some complexity in there. I'll be looking at the code and checking it all out tomorrow. Perhaps I'll end up separating out the tabs into separate files.  I was just looking to see if anyone had some killer insights before I have another slog over this process.

Comment: tested with 6000 row, 10 columns, 20 worksheets, file size 4 MB, time needed was  about 4 seconds

Comment: cheers Yahya, I think if I clean up my sheets remove the images - lower the size down - might have something.  Thanks for helping - give me something to work on.

Comment: Turns out my issue wasn't the spreadsheet good old entity framework

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to tease some extra performance out of the code but it's a question over throwaway code/performance and the deadline is quite far ahead so doesn't need to be super quick. Guess some of this is just intrest. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, you want to read & write rows in a column first, whether EPPlus or Excel COM Interop